# Upvoting comments as equivalent of Facebook "like": bad form?

Tags: discussion, comment, up-votes

Every now and then, I find comments which I like. Were I on facebook, I would put a like. Here on SX, "like" is not an available feature. The closest I can think of is upvoting. Sometimes I do, sometimes I don't. I have seen humorous comments with many upvotes, so I guess this is not too bad an idea. However, upvoting should be used to mark constructive / useful comments. Some comments I would "like" are decidedly not constructive nor useful. Is it advisable to upvote such comments or should I just leave them alone?

Comment: The rules of the site are greatly ignored by the community in many respects. So first I think you need to decide whether you want to follow the rules or follow the flock. Once this is decided, the answer is easy.

Comment: Since you are asking specifically comments (not answers/questions) I have added ([meta-tag:comments]) tag. If you want to make this information more visible, you can mention it also in the title. (For example: Upvoting comments as...)

Comment: Put likes on them to your hearts content. Nobody's gonna stop you, and you never run out of comment votes.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The limit is [30 comment votes per day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/), but few people ever reach it.

Comment: Really? I believe you, @CareBear, but this was news to me. And I think I vote comments very often :-)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I went ahead and added it to the title, because I found the question without it confusing, and it seemed pretty obviously in line with the original author's intentions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Depends on context, as usual. The main thing to consider is that comment votes are used to determine which comments are shown on page load, i.e., are in the face of every visitor from the Internet who ever looks at the post.

On the main site, $5$ top voted comments are shown; on meta sites, $15$. So, if one particularly funny comment gets upvoted to the skies, no big deal. If there are several, and they are crowding out less funny, but more useful comments, there is a problem. Withholding upvotes, or flagging for a moderator to delete obsolete / chatty comments, is appropriate then. For more, see [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments).

Comment: Links to general advice on meta.stackexchange.com should be viewed mostly as "for another perspective" rather than "for more", since there is no reason to think that the guuidelines set by *that* community will be the same as the ones set by *this* community.

Comment: My understanding is that comments are supposed to be disposable, though. So if there's something important, I'd say it should probably be added to the answer.

Comment: @trlkly Many valuable comments are posted under questions rather than under answers. Also, in practice there is a difference between practice and theory. If SE batch-deleted all comments today, a good deal of information would be lost.